# Efficient and cross-platform way to store arbitrary sort order?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, sqlite, sorting

I am currently working on an Android app where users can order their list via drag and drop in any order they want. Therefore, I must store the sort order in a variable and a column. I was thinking of giving each row a number like 100000, 200000, 300000, etc and if a user moves an item between 100000 and 200000, then its sort number becomes the average of its neighbours ie 150000. So the farther apart the numbers, the fewer times I have to "reset" the sort numbers when they converge onto each other

There are a few things I am worried about:

1. First is what is the most efficient? Do large numbers use more resources or take longer to sort? I only expect ~40 rows so if large numbers take longer to sort, I might be better off using smaller numbers and "resetting" more often.
2. Second is ensuring cross-platform compatibility in the future. For now, I only have to worry about this working with my Android app which uses Java and SQLite which haves longs with max of 2 ^ 63-1. But in the future I may have to worry about things like syncing between an iOS app which uses Objective C and maybe a web client. I am not familiar with those technologies so it would be helpful if anyone could point out any cross-compatibility problems I might have with them and how I can prevent them now so I won't have to modify my stuff later.

Thanks

Edit: Sorry I forgot to mention this but another reason I don't want to just update all the rows every time with an incrementing sort order is because not only do I have to save to the local db but I have to sync any updated changes to a BAAS. A lot of BAAS like Parse and Kinvey (what im using) do not allow you to batch save objects so every time I "reset" all the sort orders I have to make a request to my BAAS for every row instead of just one.

Comment: Are you sure a query like `UPDATE TableName SET SortOrder = SortOrder + 1 WHERE SortOrder > {The SortOrder you're inserting to + 1}` wouldn't be sufficient? I'd think SQLite would do that very efficiently with an indexed SortOrder. You could test it out. You may be overthinking this.

Comment: Oh and you can use SQLite for iOS and Web as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can just stick with the `SortOrder` being separated by one. I think you are worried about having to perform an update on tons of rows, but if you Index on `SortOrder` this won't be a problem. They will all get updated extremely fast.

I think you'll be surprised how fast a query like

```
UPDATE TableName SET SortOrder = SortOrder + 1 WHERE SortOrder > {InsertLocation + 1};
```

will run with an Index on your `SortOrder` column. If you have a lot of data and don't have the Index, you'll notice the query will take significantly longer. Try it out for yourself!

Regarding cross platform SQLite support, both iOS and the Web support SQLite, so you shouldn't have a problem there.

Comment: Hey thanks

Sorry I forgot to mention this but another reason I don't want to just update all the rows every time with an incrementing sort order is because not only do I have to save to the local db but I have to sync any updated changes to a BAAS. A lot of BAAS like Parse and Kinvey (what im using) do not allow you to batch save objects so every time I "reset" all the sort orders I have to make a request to my BAAS for every row instead of just one.

Comment: I don't know about Kinvey but I know Parse uses "smart indexing", aka they index what needs it the most.

Comment: What do you mean? My point about Parse is that they use 1 API request to save 1 ParseObject (Even if you batch 10 ParseObject saves into 1 operation it still counts as 10 API requests). So if each POJO corresponds to one row in my db and that corresponds to 1 ParseObject, if I have to update every row's sort order column every time, then I must make API requests equal to the number of rows I have. That would be expensive as Parse charges per API request nor do I want to tax their server if unnecessary.